# remove from array by index using values from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have a large array of data lets call it `this.dataSet`, I also have an array that looks like this,

`this.visibleRows = [1, 6, 52, 92, 96, 98, 100];`

This is an array of indexes, and using those indexes I will retrieve data from `this.dataSet`.

I also want to keep a record of indexes that I don't want to show in another variable `this.hiddenRows`

Using `this.visibleRows` and `this.dataSet` is it possible to get the indexes that not in `this.visibleRows`?

I thought something like,

```
this.dataSet.filter((data, index) => {
    if(this.visibleRows.indexOf(index) < 0) {
         this.hiddenRows.push(index);
    }
});
```

However the above seems to think all rows need removing?

Comment: You need to provide the data structure in `this.dataSet`.

Comment: It was mistake I splicing the array further down the code on the index

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine. I don't think that you actually need hiddenRows

```js
class DataHandler {
 
     dataset = [
     {name: 'first'},
     {name: 'second'}
    ]
    
     visibleRows = [1]
   
   hiddenRows = []
    
    getData(){
      return this.dataset.filter((d, i) => this.visibleRows.includes(i))
    }
    
    getHiddenRows(){
      return Object.keys(this.dataset).filter(i => !this.visibleRows.includes(Number(i)))
    }
   }
   
   const data = new DataHandler()
   
   console.log(data.getData())
   console.log(data.getHiddenRows())
```

If your dataset is big you can also use this approach

```js
class DataHandler {
 
     dataset = [
     {name: 'first'},
     {name: 'second'}
    ]
    
     visibleRows = [1]
   
    
    getData(){
      return this.visibleRows.map((i) => this.dataset[i] || null).filter(d => d)
    }
     getHiddenRows(){
      return Object.keys(this.dataset).filter(i => !this.visibleRows.includes(Number(i)))
    }
   }
   
   const data = new DataHandler()
   
   console.log(data.getData())
   console.log(data.getHiddenRows())
```

Answer (score 0):

may be this way perform faster. check it out
make a copy of Ur data set

```
var hiddenData = dataSet.slice();
```

then remove visible indexes from large indexes to small one
in this case U need sort visible indexes array

```
this.visibleRows = this.visibleRows.sort().reverse();
this.visibleRows.forEach(row=>{
    hiddenData.splice(row,1)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, You want to get the index of the elements from `dataSet` array which are not available in `visibleRows`. If Yes, you can simply achieve that by using [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method along with the [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const dataSet = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3', 'item 4', 'item 5', 'item 6', 'item 7', 'item 8', 'item 9', 'item 10'];

const visibleRows = [1, 3, 6, 9];

const hiddenRows = [];

dataSet.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (!visibleRows.includes(index)) {
    hiddenRows.push(index);
  }
});

console.log(hiddenRows);
```